# Losing content-type when persisting to Azure blob storage

Tags: c#, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage

I've got an Azure function which persists files sent in the request to blob storage. For some reason -- even though the files have a content-type -- they're being persisted with the `application/octet-stream` content-type, rather than say, `image/jpeg`.

```cs
var file = req.Form.Files["File"];
var blobClient = new BlobContainerClient(connection, containerName);
var blob = blobClient.GetBlobClient(fileName);
await blob.UploadAsync(file.OpenReadStream());
```

Any ideas why this is happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file, when uploaded, will not naturally figure out the content type (or keep the existing one) - it needs to be manually set.

If you don't manually set it at a blob level they will upload as a `application/octet-stream` as you've found.

Luckily it's quite simple to do, access the properties and set it directly like:

`blob.Properties.ContentType = "video/mp4";`

Comment: Thanks, it wasn't quite what I needed but it got me there. `.Properties` is readonly in the version of `Azure.Storage.Blobs` I'm using (That's 12.14.0-beta.1). I needed to do the following:
`var blobHttpHeader = new BlobHttpHeaders { ContentType = file.ContentType };
        await blob.UploadAsync( file.OpenReadStream(), new BlobUploadOptions { HttpHeaders = blobHttpHeader });`